# explanation on chown(1) POSIX spec

Tags: posix, chown

The POSIX spec for the `chown` utility [mentions in its *rationale* section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chown.html#tag_20_18_18) about the `chown user:group` syntax (formerly `chown user.group`) (emphasis mine):

> The 4.3 BSD method of specifying both owner and group was included in this volume of POSIX.1-2008 because:
>
> - There are cases where the desired end condition could not be achieved using the chgrp and chown (that only changed the user ID) utilities. **(If the current owner is not a member of the desired group and the desired owner is not a member of the current group, the chown() function could fail unless both owner and group are changed at the same time.)**

I thought the `user:group` syntax was a convenience thing. Now the above implies there are things you can do with `chown user:group` that you can't with `chgrp group; chown user`

Now that text doesn't make sense to me. In 4.3BSD, only root could change the owner a file so in any case there's no restriction in what he can do.

SysV and a few other systems allow (or used to allow) the owner of a file to change the user and group of a file to anything, but even in those system, that text above doesn't make sense to me. OK, if one does do a `chown someone-else the-file`, one cannot do `chgrp something-else the-file` afterwards because one is no longer the owner of the file, but there's nothing preventing him/her from doing the `chgrp` first (staying the owner of the file) and `chown` after, and that's not what the text above is exactly saying.

I don't understand what the *and the desired owner is not a member of the current group* has to do with the problem.

So what are the conditions for which *the chown() function could fail unless both owner and group are changed at the same time*, and on what system?

Comment: @Robert, on what system would those rules apply? On the systems I know, either you're root and you can do whatever you like or your not user1 and you can't do anything. If you're user1, depending on the system, either you can't change the owner anyway, or, when you can, then you can change the group to whatever you like, and then the user to whatever you like.

Comment: If I have in a directory that I own, a file owned by someone else, and group I am not member of, but I can read because of other permissions. Then I it is possible for me to copy it to make me the owner, and it have a new group (for which I am member). Therefore it must be as save for the OS to allow me as non-root to `chown me:my-group file` if file is in a location where I have read/write access (no sticky). I could not chgrp first as not owner. I could not chown first as this would result in file I could not create: me owning a file with group I am not member of.

Comment: @richard, no it wouldn't be _as safe_. That file could be hardlinked to another directory you don't have access to. On systems where you can link files you don't own (like Linux by default), that would mean you could claim ownership to any file by linking it to a directory you have write access to.

Comment: I found this text, it also explains why I am wrong (it is not as safe): “If you were allowed to appropriate the file, this would be a security hole. For example, the user someone could open the file, then verify its ownership and permissions (by calling fstat on the open file handle), and conclude that only a program running as someone could have produced this data. If you were able to appropriate the file, you could then change its content against someone's wishes.” — http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68439/taking-file-ownership-when-file-and-directory-is-readable-writable

Answer (score 6):

The [Microsoft Interix Unix subsystem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463219.aspx) *(now retired)* for its NT kernel dealt a little differently with user and group permissions than some others do:

> User and group information is stored in the *Security Access database*. Both users and groups are stored in the same database, but group and user names must be unique; no group can have a user's name and vice versa. *(This database replaces the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/groups` files in UNIX.)* Users and groups are created using the appropriate Windows methodology *(User Manager, Active Directory Users and Computers, or Local Users and Groups)* or with the Win32 `net user` command. *(Example shell scripts to create and remove users are included in the directory `/usr/examples/admin`.)* Users can belong to many groups.

Here are [some](http://www.systemmanager.ru/svcsunix.en/extfile/subsys/windowsntobjectsecurity.htm) more specific manual excerpts:

> In Windows, either a user or a group can own an object. This is different from UNIX, in which only a user owns an object.
>
> Windows identifies all users and groups internally by using a security identifier *(SID)*. A hashing algorithm generates SID values that are unique; no two users or groups will have the same SID.
>
> Users and groups that have permission to access an object are identified by their SID. All objects that can be secured by Windows have a discretionary access control list (DACL), which consists of separate entries called access control entries (ACEs). An ACE includes two important pieces of information: a user or group SID, and a description of how much access the individual user or group has to an object.
>
> [CHGRP](http://www.systemmanager.ru/svcsunix.en/extfile/commands/chgrp.htm)
>
> ...Change the group ID for the file ... the user invoking chgrp(1) must belong to the specified group and be the owner of the file, or have appropriate privileges.
>
> [CHOWN](http://www.systemmanager.ru/svcsunix.en/extfile/commands/chown.htm)
>
> ...The owner and group operands are both optional; however, one must be specified. If the group operand is specified, it must be preceded by a colon (:).
>
> The owner can be specified by either a numeric user ID or a user name. If a user name is also a numeric user ID, the operand is used as a user name. The group can be either a numeric group ID or a group name. If a group name is also a numeric group ID, the operand is used as a group name.
>
> For security reasons, the ownership of a file can be altered only by a process with appropriate privileges.

As I read it that means that if your user account belongs to a Windows group with sufficient privileges to modify a file's permissions that is owned by that group, then it is possible to effectively `chgrp` that file outside your user account's control. This amounts to lesser control than you might have with `chown` and explicit `user:group` parameters. In that context without the possibility of declaring `user:` *and* `:group` you never could achieve the same results as otherwise.

[Here is a link](https://lists.samba.org/archive/linux-cifs-client/2005-June/000865.html) to a detailed look at how Interix interacts with Windows ACLs with a focus on how such knowledge might apply to Samba file-systems on other Unix variants.

[Here is a link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7009/chapter2-34/index.html) to a now *obsolete* Solaris document describing the tunable `rstchown` which...

> Indicates whether the POSIX semantics for the `chown(2)` system call are in effect...

Apparently, if the parameter is set to a value of `0`...

> ...turning off POSIX semantics opens the potential for various security holes. It also opens the possibility of a **user changing ownership of a file to another user and being unable to retrieve the file** back without intervention from the user or the system administrator.

Such an option does not invalidate Solaris's [POSIX conformance](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html). Just that it is an option at all qualifies it as *conformant*:

> Although all implementations conforming to POSIX.1-2008 support all
>   the features described below, there may be **system-dependent or file
>   system-dependent configuration procedures that can remove or modify**
>   any or all of these features. Such configurations should not be made
>   if strict compliance is required.
>
> The following symbolic constants shall be defined with a value other
>   than -1. If a constant is defined with the value zero, applications
>   should use the `sysconf()`, `pathconf()`, or `fpathconf()` functions, or the
>   `getconf` utility, to determine which features are present on the system
>   at that time or for the particular pathname in question.
>
> **_POSIX_CHOWN_RESTRICTED**
>
> The use of `chown()` is restricted to a process with appropriate
>   privileges, and to changing the group ID of a file only to the
>   effective group ID of the process or to one of its supplementary group
>   IDs.

The `chown()` system function - which is the documented system call made by both the [`chown`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chown.html) and [`chgrp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chgrp.html) shell utilities - is [specified to fail](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chown.html) for numerous reasons. Among them:

> `EACCES`
>   Search permission is denied on a component of the path prefix.
>
> `ELOOP`
>   A loop exists in symbolic links encountered during resolution of the path argument.
>
> `EPERM`
>   The effective user ID does not match the owner of the file, or the calling process does not have appropriate privileges and **_POSIX_CHOWN_RESTRICTED** indicates that such privilege is required.

The behavior of granting permissions modification rights to non-root users has  never been unique to Solaris, however. There is *very excellent* - if somewhat dated - coverage of Unix file permissions in [this forum post](http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/19060-unix-file-permissions.html) in which the author states:

> Originally, Unix allowed a file owner to give away a file. A file's owner could change the owner to someone else. There was no way for a non-root user to undo this operation... BSD *[later]* removed `chown` from non-root users *...[in part because]...* it implemented disk quotas which could limit how much disk space a user could have in a filesystem... Naughty users could give away large files to sneek past the quotas.
>
> Today, it is not easy to say if a non-root can `chown` a file. Many versions of Unix allow **both** behaviors...

Another good - and more recent - [mailing-list post](http://www.ale.org/pipermail/ale/2007-November/099350.html) quotes this and continues:

> > The default with most OS's is for `chown` to be restricted to root only. And there is a consensus that it should stay this way for security considerations. If a non-root user does change the owner of a file and any execute bit is on, the `SUID` and `SGID` bits must be cleared. This may or may not happen with `root`.
>
> I think that last paragraph says it nicely.
>
> That article also references `CAP_CHOWN` to control that
>   facility on Linux *(that should only affect the `POSIX_CHOWN_RESTRICTED` behavior)*. There is also the `CAP_FOWNER` capability, that's a little different in behavior.

And as [you point out in 2003](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.shell/2003-04/0482.html):

> Note that at least on HPUX, you can change the owner of your 
>   files *(to `root` for instance)* even if you're not a priviledged 
>   user...

...which depended upon a configuration `setprivgroup` parameter.

In any case in which a non-root user can manipulate file-permissions it is conceivable, as is mentioned in the *rationale* quoted in your question, that a user might `chown` a file which that user owns so that it is owned by another user. If the file's group ownership and the `chown`ing user's groups do not align then the user would no longer be capable of modifying that file.

In this scenario `chown` *then* `chgrp` would fail as the user would no longer have permissions to alter that file's permissions, whereas `chown user:group` - so long as *group* is among the user's own - would succeed.

There are *probably* numerous other niche situations that might result similarly, which might include directory *sticky* and/or *setgid* bits, file-system and/or implementation-specific access-control lists. [This thread](http://thr3ads.net/zfs-discuss/2010/02/585572-usr-bin-chgrp-destroys-ACLs) is interesting, for instance. The countless permutations are far beyond my own feeble grasp - which is why this answer is wikied. If you're reading this, you believe it is worth improving, and you believe you know how - **please do**.

There is also extensive documentation on the various possible effects of file permissions, tree traversal, and symbolic links that might effect a similar failure with regards to `-R`ecursive `chown` applications here:

From [POSIX XRAT](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html#tag_21_03_00_01) section headings *Third* and *Fourth Domains* :

> Generally, users specifying the option for a file hierarchy traversal wish to operate on a single, physical hierarchy, and therefore symbolic links, which may reference files outside of the hierarchy, are ignored. For example, chown owner file is a different operation from the same command with the -R option specified. In this example, the behavior of the command `chown` `owner` `file` is described here, while the behavior of the command [`chown -R`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chown.html) owner file is described in the third and fourth domains.
>
> ...There is a security issue with defaulting to a logical walk. Historically, the command [`chown -R`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chown.html) user file has been safe for the superuser because *setuid* and *setgid* bits were lost when the ownership of the file was changed. If the walk were logical, changing ownership would no longer be safe because a user might have inserted a symbolic link pointing to any file in the tree. Again, this would necessitate the addition of an option to the commands doing hierarchy traversal to not indirect through the symbolic links, and historical scripts doing recursive walks would instantly become security problems. While this is mostly an issue for system administrators, it is preferable to not have different defaults for different classes of users.
>
> ...
>
> In 4.3 BSD, `chgrp` during tree traversal changed the group of the symbolic link, not the target. Symbolic links in 4.4 BSD did not have owner, group, mode, or other standard UNIX system file attributes.

And from the POSIX [`chgrp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chgrp.html) page proper there is this which points to a possible incomplete `-R`ecursive action, or at least to what *used* to be:

> The System V and BSD versions use different exit status codes. Some implementations used the exit status as a count of the number of errors that occurred; this practice is unworkable since it can overflow the range of valid exit status values. The standard developers chose to mask these by specifying only 0 and >0 as exit values.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - glad you understood. ∆that∆ is kinduva mess because im not very good with the whole permissions thing - especially when SE attributes are involved. The connection is loose - links!=ch{grp,own} but i figured if the POSIX guys would go to so much trouble to spell it out (theres a big chart on the page, too) then for the same reason a link might cause problems then so might two -R actions. It wouldnt break anything if youve got both feet in - user and group - as you say, but if youre already 1 off.. Anyway, i wikied it for a reason. Not really my forte. Sorry.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of -R. One could imaging that you could loose search or read access to a directory upon the chgrp which would prevent you from changing the permissions of files in there, but then again with the traditional Unix ways to handle ownership or permissions, I can't see how to make it happen. An other area worth investigating I think would be the NFSv4 ACLs on systems that support it (Solaris, FreeBSD, SUSE...)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - is there an aspect of your question this post does not answer?

Comment: thanks a lot for that thorough research. It'd be nice if you could add an example with the NT Unix subsystem where the POSIX text applies. I'm not sure how bounties work with community wiki answers though. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I didn't care for the points and never have. I was just hoping I didn't screw it up. I'm not surre I get the *it'd be nice* part though - do you mean NT Unix 4? Microsoft's official docs claim POSIX compliance at least for when it was still Interix, I and they state a little strangely *`chgrp` `chown` ... may not behave as you expect...*

Answer (score 1):

Assumption 1: the rules for determining whether `chown` succeeds check the target user and group parts independently, i.e. they are of the form `user_condition(target_uid, other_environment_parameters) && group_condition(target_gid, other_environment_parameters)`.

Assumption 2: `chown(file, -1, -1)` succeeds.

Assumption 3: the rules for determining whether `chown` succeeds do not depend on which group the file currently belongs to.

Corollary: if `chown(file, uid, gid)` would succeed then so would `chown(file, -1, gid) && chown(file, uid, -1)`.

I don't know of a Unix variant that would violate any of these assumptions, they seem pretty safe.

This sentence has the look of something that somebody on the committee said when they were tired after hours of debating how many options could fit on the head of a `ps` call — or that the secretary mistranscribed — and that nobody caught during review. After all, there are other, good reasons to allow the user and group to be changed automatically, including the performance reason also cited in the POSIX rationale, as well as atomicity (ah, if only there was a single call to change ownership and permissions).

---

A case where assumption 3 could be wrong is on a system where a process can get the capability to change file owners but only if they have write permission on the file. While somewhat realistic, I don't know of any system where this is the case. Then `chgrp` to a group from a process that running neither as root nor as the user owning the file could make the file off-limit for a later `chown`.

---

For a recursive call, there are edge cases where a whole pass of `chgrp` followed by a whole pass of `chown` can fail when a single pass would succeed. This isn't a very convincing argument because it involves directories that the owner does not have the permission to traverse, and an application that wanted to protect against all such cases would need to fiddle with permissions anyway. Nonetheless it technically meets the condition of this rationale. Assume that the running process has effective user `alice`, effective group `staff`, and the capability to change file owners arbitrarily (not just to give them away; several unix variants have such a capability, though it is rarely granted to non-root processes).

```
$ ls -ld dir dir/file
d---rwx---  2 charlie  staff        1024 Apr  1  1970 dir
drw-rw----  2 charlie  staff          42 Apr  1  1970 file
$ chgrp -R students dir
$ chown -R bob dir
chown: dir: permission denied
```

Comment: Note that POSIX is not only about Unix. There are many non-Unix OSes that have a POSIX subsystem/API (for instance Microsoft Windows NT). I'm not sure those conditions are enough to claim the corollary. The `chgrp` or `chown` could have side effects that affect the ability to do the other one. For instance `chown` removes the ability to `chgrp`, that's a fact. `chgrp` clears the setuid/setgid bit, it may clear some form of ACL or other form of security context...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas We agree that `chown` followed by `chgrp` could fail, but the question is about `chgrp` followed by `chown`. Hmmm, security context… maybe in a system with mandatory access control, `chgrp` could taint a file and make it no longer chownable? That seems far-fetched.

Comment: Maybe not far fetched. I don't know much about NFSv4/WinNT ACLs but I suspect there's something there that could make this kind of thing happen (and/or invalidate your 3rd assumption). Still, that text is quite  specific and whoever wrote it would have had a specific example in mind. Maybe it was written by some Microsoft people.

Comment: re your latest edit. With chown -R bob:students, alice would still loose search permissions on `dir`, so for that to work, `chown` would need to process files depth first and I don't know of any implementation that does. So it's an almost valid case where chgrp+chown would fail where chmod u:g could not, but that doesn't really add up with the text of the rationale.

Comment: The unreviewed secretary mistranscription and the edge-case recursive `chown` theories appear to conflict.

Comment: This answer in no way *draw[s] from credible and/or official sources.* It even opens with *Assumption:*...