# Does chown command allow to set group different from user group?

Tags: command, group, chown, ownership

It may be a stupid question, but I don't understand a detail about the command `chown`. I haven't found any explanation for this detail yet, maybe because it's so obvious to everyone.

When you change a file ownership, you can set a user parameter and a group parameter, using the following basic syntax:

```
chown <username>:<groupname> <filename>
```

This syntax allows you to insert into the  field a user which belongs to a certain group, and to insert into the  field a group.
When I learned about the chown command for the first time I thought the groupname must be the same as the user group.
But then I found out that the groupname can refer to a different group from the one the user belongs to.

Does this mean that you can set ownership to a user and a group, with the group being unrelated to the user group?
If yes, it seems to me that this issue conflicts with what I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271806/why-do-you-have-to-be-a-member-of-a-group-to-make-that-group-the-group-owner-of). Or am I just getting confused?

Thank you!

Comment: In what way does it conflict with what you are reading in that other Q/A? A file is created with the ownership of the user+group that created the file. You may then change the owner and group with `chmod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "conflict" in your [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271806/why-do-you-have-to-be-a-member-of-a-group-to-make-that-group-the-group-owner-of) refers to a non-root user. Non-root users can only change the group of a file to a group he belongs to (due to the reasons mentioned there).

However, `root` himself could set any user and any group to any file, and the owner of the file doesn't have to belong to the group. So there's no conflict.